# Secure Auth0 post registration action

Tags: jwt, auth0

In the example auth0 provides for [Storing an Auth0 user id in a remote system](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/flows-and-triggers/post-user-registration-flow#store-the-auth0-user-id-in-a-remote-system) it posts to an unprotected endpoint.  Are there headers or something I can add to the request that my endpoint can check to make sure not just anyone can post a email and create a user?

```
const axios = require("axios");

/**
 * @param {Event} event - Details about registration event.
 */
exports.onExecutePostUserRegistration = async (event) => {
  await axios.post("https://my-api.exampleco.com/users", { params: { email: event.user.email }});
};
```

Comment: Yeah, they have nothing about it in documentation. As if you are able to call any user profile related API w/o tokens (( Were you able to get things done?

Answer (score -1):

The example uses the *axios* library to execute the request. *axios* is a mature Javascript HTTP client with a ton of features. You can easily add a header, e.g.:

```
await axios.post(
    "https://my-api.exampleco.com/users",
    {
        headers: { 'Authorization: supersecret' },
        params: { email: event.user.email }
    }
);
```

Also refer to the *axios* documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios.

If *axios* is not suitable, other npm packages can also be used.

Comment: What is supersecret, something I get from auth0?

Comment: The example shows Auth0 calling one of your APIs. If the API is protected and uses authentication, then you must provide whatever your API expects for authentication. It's just an example to show how you can add headers.

Comment: Right I guess my question is more Auth0 centric than how to attach headers, I was wondering if theres some sort of token included in that event that I could use to signal the request was coming from a trusted source.  It seems like you either need to do a M2M call to auth0 or maintain your own secret.

Comment: I'm not aware of any special token. The code would need to be the same as if you were accessing the endpoint from anywhere else. You will probably need a credential. So it boils down to the question how to store a credential in Auth0 and make it accessible to Actions. Unfortunately, I don't have the answer.

Comment: The Author asks how to get auth token in onExecutePostUserRegistration action.